# jQuery issue while submitting the form

Tags: jquery, forms

The problem that I'm facing is when I click on the submit button in the form. It's not validating but directly posting to the php script but when I click on text boxes it's validating perfectly. I need to validate the form before submission.

Javascript Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Begin of Ready document
    $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#fname").blur(function(){

                if($("#fname").val() == "" ){

                    $("#fname").focus();
                    $("#fvalid").html("First Name Cannot be Blank");
                    return false;

                }else{
                    $("#fvalid").html("");
                    return true;
                }

            });

            $("#lname").blur(function(){

                if($("#lname").val() == "" ){

                    $("#lname").focus();
                    $("#lvalid").html("Last Name Cannot be Blank");
                    return false;

                }else{
                    $("#lvalid").html("");
                    return true;
                }

            });
</script>
```

HTML Code

```
<table class="content" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="padding-top:20px;">
    <tr>
        <td class="contentfont">First Name<span class="sup">*</span></td>
        <td class="contentfont">:</td>
        <td><input type="textbox" name="fname" class="textbox" id="fname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><span id="fvalid" class="failed"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="contentfont">Last Name<span class="sup">*</span></td>
        <td class="contentfont">:</td>
        <td><input type="textbox" class="textbox" name="lname" id="lname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><span id="lvalid" class="failed"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit" class="register" value="Register Now" id="submit"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit" class="register" value="Register Now" id="submit"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Can some one please help fix this?

Comment: `$("FormId").submit();` use this or follow this https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are validation on `blur`. this means, when you leave a textbox, this event fires. But you did not write any code for validating the form on submit event. You should do this:

```
$("#formID").submit(function(){
    var valid = true;
    if($("#fname").val() == "" ){
      $("#fname").focus();
      $("#fvalid").html("First Name Cannot be Blank");
      valid = false;
    }

    if($("#lname").val() == "" ){
         $("#lname").focus();
         $("#lvalid").html("Last Name Cannot be Blank");
         valid = false;
     }

  return valid;

});
```